# GolangでfyneのNewFileSaveがエラーが出てました

Tags: go

Golangのfyneで簡単なGUIメモアプリ作りたいですが、「Save」を押すとエラーが出ました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラー：

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x70dbed]

goroutine 26 [running]:
fyne.io/fyne/v2/dialog.(*fileDialog).makeUI.func2()
/home/kotoharu/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/v2/dialog/file.go:104 +0x34d
fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget.(*Button).Tapped(0xc0000c0320, 0xc000dfd300)
/home/kotoharu/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget/button.go:177 +0x74
fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/glfw.(*window).mouseClicked.func7()
/home/kotoharu/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/glfw/window.go:802 +0x38
fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/glfw.(*window).runEventQueue(0xc0001201c0)
/home/kotoharu/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/glfw/window.go:1268 +0x7a
created by fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/glfw.(*gLDriver).createWindow.func1
/home/kotoharu/go/src/fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/glfw/window.go:1292 +0x113
exit status 2
```

コード：

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/theme"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/dialog"
)

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myApp.Settings().SetTheme(theme.DarkTheme())

    window := myApp.NewWindow("text-pad")
    window.Resize(fyne.NewSize(640, 480))

    le := widget.NewMultiLineEntry()
    le.SetPlaceHolder("enter")

    //Button
    bt := widget.NewButton("save as", func () {
        saveDialog := dialog.NewFileSave(nil, window)
        saveDialog.Show()
    })

    box := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(
        layout.NewBorderLayout(nil, bt, nil, nil),
        le, bt,
    )

    window.SetContent(box)
    window.ShowAndRun()

}
```

原因がわかりません、何が間違っているでしょうか?

ありがとうございました

Comment: エラーの原因は callback function として `nil` を渡しているためです。[NewFileSave](https://pkg.go.dev/fyne.io/fyne/v2/dialog#NewFileSave) によれば `WriteCloser` を渡します。`saveDialog := dialog.NewFileSave(func(f fyne.URIWriteCloser, err error) { if f != nil { f.Write([]byte(le.Text)) } }, window)`

Comment: 問題解決しました。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーの原因は callback function として nil を渡しているためです。NewFileSave によれば WriteCloser を渡します。

```
saveDialog := dialog.NewFileSave(func(f fyne.URIWriteCloser, err error) { if f != nil { f.Write([]byte(le.Text)) } }, window)
```